# NoSuchMethodError when using hbase-server

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

In order to use TableMapper, I included the hbase-server dependencies to my hadoop project. hbase-shaded-client and hbase-server both have 1.1.2 version.

But when trying to run the hadoop job, I have an error that seems related to security:

```
 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.constructSecretProvider(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;Ljava/util/Properties;Z)Lorg/apache/hadoop/security/authentication/util/SignerSecretProvider;
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.constructSecretProvider(HttpServer2.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.<init>(HttpServer2.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.<init>(HttpServer2.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$Builder.build(HttpServer2.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.build(WebApps.java:261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.client.MRClientService.serviceStart(MRClientService.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceStart(MRAppMaster.java:1107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$4.run(MRAppMaster.java:1519)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1448)
2016-08-22 11:04:29,010 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Does someone have this problem before?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you share your code details and how this job of yours is executed?

Answer (score 0):

hbase shaded client seems to pull in an un-shaded version of servlet api classes. This can cause issues when deploying into web servers or any other framework that expects a different version of the servlet api to be available.